# Use winding number version of Cauchy Integral Formula to show that inverse of image is path integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, and suppose $f'(a)\ne 0$ for some $a \in U$.

Show that there is an $r > 0$ such that $f$ is injective on $B(a, r)$ and that its inverse g is given on the image of such a disk by

$$g(w) = \frac{1}{2πi} \int_{γ}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz$$

where $γ(t) = a + re^{it}, t ∈ [0, 2π]$.

[Hint: You may find it helpful to use the winding number version of Cauchy Integral Formula.]

I feel like this question is likely to have been asked previously. However, I've been searching for a long time, both on stack exchange and google, and cannot find anything useful. I would really appreciate a detailed explanation of how to approach this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: By the inverse function theorem, there is an $r > 0$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $f(a)$ such that $f : B(a, r + \varepsilon) \to V$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. It is easy to check that $g = f^{-1}$ is also holomorphic. Apply Cauchy integral formula for $g(w)$ on $f(\gamma) = \partial f(B(a, r))$. You probably need to use the fact that $f$ is orientation preserving when you make a change of variables.